# What will the data be if I insert a C# 'NULL' into a DataBase?

Tags: c#, database, null

I've learned that the `DBNull` & C# normal `null` are totally different things and C# treats `DBNull.Value` as some weird random thing, but what will database treat the C# `null` as a value?

Will the database treat the C# `null` as empty or a string or some random things as well?

Comment: Null will be null in the database.

Comment: Depends on your data access layer. EF will map C# null to sql null.

Comment: -1, why didn't you try?

Comment: Are you using Entity as an ORM? The column will be null if the answer to that question is yes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It would be better if you post your findings vs what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you use to access the database.

- Entity Framework will map a database `null` to C# `null`, in fact it doesn't use `DBNull` at all.
- SQL DAO (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand for instance) uses `DBNull` to represent a database `null` and `null to represent the lack of something.

Other data access layers may use different standards, or one of these.

For instance, the following queries:

```
SELECT NULL FROM whatever WHERE 1=2
SELECT NULL FROM whatever WHERE 1=1
```

When called by the following:

Entity Framework (using `from .. select`)

- Empty result set (an `IEnumerable` that never returns a value)
- A single result set containing `null`

Entity Framework (using `First()`)

- Exception, since there are no results
- `null`

Entity Framework (using `FirstOrDefault()`)

- `null`
- `null`

SQL DAO (using `ExecuteScalar()`)

- `null`
- `DBNull`